# Recurrent points of a contraction of a compact metric space

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

Let $T: X \to X$ be a contraction of a compact metric space. How many recurrent points does it have? Can it be mixing?

Being contraction of a compact metric space means that $d(T(x),T(y)))\le kd(x,y)$ for some $0\le k<1$. We are looking for points fulfilling condition $d(T^n(x),x)<\epsilon$ for $n$ greater than some $N$. My intuition is that we should look for the recurrent points only among fixed points.

Comment: Your description of the defining property of recurrent point is a bit sloppy as you leave out the quantifiers (for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$ etc.). This is very important. Concerning your intuition, what do you know about the fixed points of $T$?

Comment: There is exactly one fixed point of $T$ from Banach fixed point theorem.

Comment: Correct. Clearly every fixed point is a recurrent point. Moreover, the Banach fixed point theorem tells you also that the sequence $(T^n(x))_n$ converges to the unique fixed point for every (!) $x \in X$. Following your intuition you might want to use this to prove that every non-fixed point is not recurrent.